# Call SSL endpoint from spring-boot app

Tags: ssl, spring-security, https, spring-boot, truststore

I have a spring-boot intranet webapp which need not be ssl secured as it is used within company.

The app calls an external https endpoint. To call the https endpoint I used InstallCert.java to generate a new trust store and import the certificate needed to call the https url using the procedure shown here.

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Doing >java InstallCert hosturl  generated jssecacerts trust store and imported the certificate

I have the following as my application.proeprties

```
 server.port: 8080
 server.contextPath=/mpservice
 management.port: 9001
 management.address: 127.0.0.1
 logging.file=mpservice.log
 logging.level.root=INFO
 logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

 server.ssl.key-store=C:/Users/cho4157/Downloads/InstallCert/jssecacerts
 server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
 server.ssl.client-auth=need
 server.ssl.trust-store=C:/Users/cho4157/Downloads/InstallCert/jssecacerts
 server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
```

The tomcat server starts fine as the logs show below but When I hit the endpoints the browser says that localhost didn't send any data.

```
 2016-08-01 19:18:20.968  INFO 16944 --- [main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9001 (https)
    2016-08-01 19:18:20.970 DEBUG 16944 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [server.ports] PropertySource with highest search precedence
    2016-08-01 19:18:20.970 DEBUG 16944 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [server.ports] PropertySource with highest search precedence
    2016-08-01 19:18:20.976  INFO 16944 --- [main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
    2016-08-01 19:18:21.418  INFO 16944 --- [main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https)
```

When I comment out server.ssl.* properties in application.properties everything works fine except posting to the https endpoint which throws the below exception as expected. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

I also tried setting following system properties

```
static
    {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Users\\jojo\\Downloads\\InstallCert\\jssecacerts");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\Users\\jojo\\Downloads\\InstallCert\\jssecacerts");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");            
    }
```

even with the above piece of code I was getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

I have been trying to get this configuration working for the past 2 days with little success. Please help.